# Match all the strings before a char and exclude n number of string

Tags: regex

What I have here is a string

```
sdsdsfd2312341232434545:4343523543435454
```

I want to get the values that are before the `:` char and also wants to exclude 16 chars to get

```
sdsdsfd
```

I have tried by using the expression

```
^.*(?=(\:).)
```

which matches all the strings before `:`. I want to exclude 16 chars before all the strings before `:` keyword. How do one do that? I want to return the `sdsdsfd` and `2312341232434545` too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
.*?(?=.{16}:)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LEmEXo/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `.*?`: Match 0 or more characters (non-greedy)
- `(?=.{16}:)`: Lookahead to assert that there are 16 characters followed by a colon ahead

**Alternative Approach**

You can use avoid using lookahead by using a capture group here:

```
(.*?).{16}:
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/LEmEXo/2)